# What to type after git am --show-current-patch

Tags: git

I am trying to rebase my feature branch onto master. I run the following first:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase master
```

There are apparently some conflicts:

```
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: My commit 1
Applying: My commit 2
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M       path/to/file.cpp
M       path/to/file.hpp
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging path/to/file.hpp
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in path/to/file.hpp
Auto-merging path/to/file.cpp
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in path/to/file.cpp
error: Failed to merge in the changes.
hint: Use 'git am --show-current-patch' to see the failed patch
Patch failed at 0002 My commit 2
Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
"git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
```

I have followed the response and also some advice on the internet to run `git am --show-current-patch` which gives me:

```
commit xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Author: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Date:   xxxxxxxxxx

    My Commit 2

diff --git a/path/to/file.cpp b/path/to/file.cpp
index xxxxxxx..yyyyyyy 123456
--- a/path/to/file.cpp
+++ b/path/to/file.cpp
... (Some changes here)
:
```

It is waiting for me to type something and it looks like I can accept/reject changes. But I really can't find any guide for what I can type, other than that I can quit by pressing `q`. What else can I do in this status?

Comment: You don't think it's the pager? See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/less.1.html and see if that's it.

Comment: The command just shows what the failed patch is and you have seen it. Just press q to quit. This command is optional. The main task here is to edit the files to resolve the conflicts.

Comment: So this is no difference between `git am show-current-patch` and opening a text editor myself to view the conflicts? And the only thing I can do after running that is `q` (quit)?

Comment: Sorry @matt could you explain the linkage here. What is the relationship with linux? I am relatively new to git.

Comment: The "linkage" is that `less` is the default pager, so if that's what you're seeing, then to know what you can type you'd read the manual for `less`.

Comment: Git generally runs all "large output" operations through the pager you choose. If you didn't choose a pager yourself, you get the system-defined choice, whatever that is. (That's more or less what @matt said but with some caveats, since some Git installations don't use `less`.)

Answer (score 0):

Note: you are using an old version of Git.  Current versions of Git do not use `git am` when rebasing.  (Run `git --version` to see which version you have.  The current version is now 2.33, and rebase was changed to use the `-m` option by default in Git 2.26.)

The old version of `git rebase`, using `git-rebase--am` internally to run `git am -3` on patch files, will leave you in this state after a conflict.  The new one leaves you in a very similar state but there's no `git am --show-current-patch` at all; most people never found that useful in the first place.

If you *do* find this useful for some reason, note that when you get around to upgrading Git, you can either force a `git am` based rebase with `git rebase --apply`, or configure `rebase.backend` to change the default back.  In any case, read through the entire patch, one page at a time, using your pager: most likely you just need to use the space bar to go forward one page at a time until you reach the end.  The pager may quit on its own at that point, or force you to quit it manually.

Otherwise, just quit out of your pager—you can probably just type `q` here at the `:` prompt—and go on to looking at the conflicted files and fixing up the conflicts.

Note: I personally find that setting `merge.conflictStyle` to `diff3` improves the ability to fix conflicts directly in a file editor (e.g., `vim path/to/conflicted/file`) without needing any fancy merge tools.  The `diff3` style conflicts are sometimes quite a bit longer than the default `merge` style, though, as the `merge` style takes Git's best effort at merging and leaves only the conflicting parts, while the old `diff3` style shows you the full conflict, including parts that Git would have merged on its own.